# navigaiton bar frame is wrong when a custom window displaying

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uinavigationcontroller

i hava a new custom UIWindow to show fullSrceen ViewController that only support 
 `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft`

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
```

a single button tap it to open "set window.hidden = NO"

```
- (void)show {
    UIWindowScene *scence = [UIApplicationsharedApplication].connectedScenes.allObjects.firstObject;
    self.window = [[CustomWindow alloc]initWithWindowScene:scence];
    CustomViewController *vc = [[CustomViewController alloc]init];;
    self.window.rootViewController = vc;
    self.window.hidden = NO;
    self.window.windowLevel = 2;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

and a single buton to close "set window.hidden = YES",

```
- (void)close {
    self.window.hidden = YES;
    self.window = nil;
}
```

all thing working well，But when I open window and I go back to the background, and I go into the foreground, and I close window, `navigationbar` is out of position.

[Portrait state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqteq.png)

[Landscape state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uaxr4.png)

[background state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuSjN.png)

[navigation bar wrong position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3wFw.png)

[code is here](https://github.com/mraandy/Rotation-Demo)

Comment: Why create a new account and question instead of editing and fixing [your previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61584530/navigation-bar-is-an-landscape-status-how-to-update-it)?

Answer (score 0):

i had fix this bug.
using presentViewController a temp vc before display custom window.

```
- (IBAction)showApp:(id)sender {
    UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
    self.tempVc = vc;
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:^{
        [self.app show];
    }];
}
```